# Image Upload Using Vue, Node/Express and Multer

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vuejs2, multer

So, there's a problem... I am trying to upload the image to the folder as soon as it is changed by using a method, but nothing shows me any errors or something, but it does not save an image to my folder. Here are the codes:

Account.vue (localhost:8081/account) template

```
<label class="profileImg" for="profileImg"><img :src="profileImg" alt="Profilio nuotrauka"></label>
<input name="profileImg" id="profileImg" accept="image/*" @change="uploadProfileImg" class="mt-3" style="display: none" type="file">
```

Account.vue script

```
async uploadProfileImg () {
  try {
    await VendorService.uploadProfileImg({
      id: this.$store.state.vendor.id
      // otherImg: this.otherImg
    })
  } catch (error) {
    this.error = error.response.data.error
  }
}
```

VendorService.js

```
uploadProfileImg () {
  return Api().post('account')
}
```

Api.js

```
export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8082/`
  })
}
```

App.js

```
const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

require('./routes')(app)
```

routes.js

```
app.post('/account',
  VendorsController.uploadProfileImg)
```

VendorsController.js

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '../../tmpUploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, req.body.id + '_profileImg')
  }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('profileImg')

async uploadProfileImg (req, res) {
try {
  // const { id } = req.body
  await upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send('Fail!')
    } else {
      return res.send('Success')
    }
  })
  // cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(`../../tmpUploads/${id}_profileImg`, {
  //   public_id: `${id}_profileImg`,
  //   overwrite: true
  // }, function (result) {
  //   console.log(result)
  // })
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send({
      error: 'Something went wrong'
    })
  }
}
```

and yes, of course I am importing all the required modules.

Comment: No solution? Even very experienced programmers don’t know what’s the problem?

Comment: @a-domeika sorry, I don't have an solution for your problem, but a very good tutorial about this topic can be found here: https://bezkoder.com/node-js-express-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try changing path omitting level up directories like this

**tmpUploads/**

To check if your file has been handled

```js
console.log(req.file)
```

The output will look like this

```js
{ 
    fieldname: 'profileImg',
    originalname: 'download.jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'tmpUploads/',
    filename: '1533819783059_profileImg',
    path: 'tmpUploads/1533819783059_profileImg',
    size: 11320 
}
```

Comment: Use FormData object for send to API.